# How do I reference and expanded REST API field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api

I am using SharePoint 2013 Rest API and I have successfully used $expand but I'm having a hard time referencing what I have expanded.
Here's what I see in developer tool:
[image]

This does not work  - **data.d.resutlts[0].AssistantChief.EMail**

```
var projNum = '402-I-001';

var endPointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('Project Module')/items?$select=AssistantChief/EMail,&$expand=AssistantChief/Id";

jQuery.ajax({ 
    url: endPointUrl, 
    type: "GET", 
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }, 
    success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
        detailComplete(data); // Returns JSON collection of the results
    }, 
    error: function (err) { 
        alert("Error Occured:" + JSON.stringify(err)); 
    }    
});

$("td#assistantChief").append(data.d.resutlts[0].AssistantChief.EMail).html();
```

Comment: is that jQuery selector code within the detailComplete() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can see that the Ajax request is working correctly. So, there is no issue fetching data from the list as we can see the data logged in console.

The issue is when you are trying to bind that data to html because of a typo in your code.

It should be **`results`** and not **`resutlts`**.

Replace, **`data.d.resutlts[0].AssistantChief.EMail`** with **`data.d.results[0].AssistantChief.EMail`**.

So, your html would be:

```
$("td#assistantChief").append(data.d.results[0].AssistantChief.EMail).html();
```

Comment: Oh my! Good catch.  That fixed the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax right off the hop with the first var. There is a typo in your last line. Also, try using deferred. I would need the list to confirm if the result set returns the property you are referencing, but hopefully this helps

```
var endPointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('Project Module')/items?$select=AssistantChief/EMail,&$expand=AssistantChief/Id"

getData(sRestApiRequestUrl ).then(function (spData) {
    detailComplete(spData);
});
```

function getData(query) {

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();
$.ajax({
    url: query,
    type: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (results) {
        deferred.resolve(results);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});

  return deferred.promise();
}

function detailComplete(spData) {
    var chief = spData.d.AssistantChief.Email;
    $("td#assistantChief").append(chief);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to perform append operation inside ajax success method `success: function (data) { }` or inside `detailComplete()` function.
Dont chain `.html()` at the end of `.append()` as `.html()` again will return entire html of the selector